# Error restoring db in Azure PostgreSQL Flexible server: 'extension "azure" is not allow-listed'

Tags: postgresql, azure

I'm using pgAdmin to backup/restore a database from one Azure PostgreSQL Flexible server to another. The source server was created last year, the destination server is new.

The restore process fails early with the error:

> ERROR: extension "azure" is not allow-listed for "azure_pg_admin" users in Azure Database for PostgreSQL

I came across this post https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/introducing-ability-to-allow-list-extensions-in-postgresql/ba-p/3219124 announcing recent changes to PostgreSQL Flexible Server. If I'm reading this correctly, my new database server is affected by this change and I need to allow specific extensions under the "azure.extensions" server parameter.

In the backup file I can see:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS azure WITH SCHEMA public;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;
```

And in Azure Portal I can see "UUID-OSSP" under the new "azure.extensions" server parameter, though there's nothing called just "azure". I enabled UUID-OSSP but the restore process still fails with the same error.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue which was:
"uuid-ossp" is not allow-listed for "azure_pg_admin" users in Azure Database for PostgreSQL

I found out that it has something to do with postgres version. I was using latest 16.1 version for azure postgres sql.
I downgraded it to 15 and finally was able to saw uuid_ossp in azure extension in server parameters tab.

Answer (score -3):

It's suggestable to install TimescaleDB that is having the package of supportive extension.

1. To learn abot TimescaleDB. (https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/)
2. Change the Postgres's parameters for ***"shared_preload_libraries"***
3. After creating extension

   CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;

Follow the entire procedure from the below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-extensions

Comment: How does that resolve the error I pasted in the question?